# Upload a file attachment without apex:inputfile

Tags: apex, visualforce, developer

I think the title explains it all. I am having a hard time finding a way to upload an image attachment without using the apex:inputfile component. I am building a UI free of any apex components. I am leveraging javascript remoting for all my asynchronous calls to the server. I simply want to grab the value from the input file with an API like fileReader and send back the base64 to the server -- Or something similar to then insert the Attachment record. Any ideas?

Comment: Use html input type file and grab the value in javascript and send it to server through remoting

Answer (score 0):

Yes, well I tried that to no avail. the return when I try to view the file is just a square. the fields I am using are

```
@RemoteAction
public static string submitExamRegistration(string studentId,string enrollmentId,string scheduleClassId,string file,string fileName,string registrationEmail,string examDate){
    Exam__c e = new Exam__c();
    e.Student__c = studentId;
    e.Class__c = enrollmentId;
    e.Exam_Date__c = date.parse(examDate);
    e.Scheduled_Class__c = scheduleClassId;
    e.status__c = 'Needs Verification';
    e.Exam_Results_Post_to_Site__c = false;
    insert e;

    Attachment a = new Attachment();
    a.parentId = e.Id;
    a.body = blob.valueOf(file);
    a.name = fileName;

    insert a;
    return null;
}
```

The body of the Attachment expects a blob to be the value. So I tried taking the html input file value which theoretically is a blob, but I sent back as a string datatype then turned it into a blob. I have also tried converting the image into a base64 and decoding through apex. Still get the same result of it returning a square when viewing the attachment.